# name of defined constants in boost.preprocessor

Tags: c++, boost

This defines are fix, I can not change them (third party lib)

```
#define X_ERR_OK (0)
#define X_ERR_FOO (816)
#define X_ERR_OTHER (842)
// .. and more
```

There is a little function, which returns the name of the error code (my code, I can change it)

```
#define X_ERR_CASE( e ) case e: return #e
const char* err_name( int err ) {
    switch( err ) {
    X_ERR_CASE( X_ERR_OK );
    X_ERR_CASE( X_ERR_FOO );
    X_ERR_CASE( X_ERR_OTHER );
    }
    return "<unknown>";
}
```

this works. Now I found boost.preprocessor a smart lib and try to use it:

```
#define XX_ERR_CASE( r, _, e ) case e: return BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(e);
#define XX_ERRORS( seq ) \
    const char* err_name2( int err ) { \
        switch( err ) { \
        BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH( XX_ERR_CASE, _, seq ) \
        } \
        return "<unknown>";  }

XX_ERRORS(
    (X_ERR_OK)
    (X_ERR_FOO)
    (X_ERR_OTHER)
)
```

but this don't works, because the output is not the name of the define but the number. For example I want to have: `X_ERR_FOO`, but I get `(816)`

If I change `XX_ERR_CASE` to

```
#define XX_ERR_CASE( r, _, e ) case e: return #e;
```

I get `BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD(((816)) ((842)) (nil))`

How I get `X_ERR_FOO` calling `err_name(816)`?

Comment: Unfortunately, the macros contained inside an argument of a function-like macro are immediately replaced *before* substitution (of the parameters), so you can't pass macro names around. However, you can inhibit the expansion by a `#` or a `##`. I.e. you `#define E(M) (E, #E)` and use it to create the sequence as `E(X_ERR_OK)E(X_ERR_FOO)` and so on. [Live example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf245740a9d01bd3)

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6401e0af6b75e700

Comment: that works! Thank You to dyp and cv_and_he

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that this is acceptable, but I'll add it anyway in case it helps. With this approach you need to change the way you call `XX_ERRORS`, its arguments need to have their `X_` prefix removed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define X_ERR_OK (0)
#define X_ERR_FOO (816)
#define X_ERR_OTHER (842)


#define XX_ERR_CASE( r, _, e ) case BOOST_PP_CAT(X_,e): return "X_" BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(e);
#define XX_ERRORS( seq ) \
    const char* err_name2( int err ) { \
        switch( err ) { \
        BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH( XX_ERR_CASE, _, seq ) \
        } \
        return "<unknown>";  }

XX_ERRORS(
    (ERR_OK)
    (ERR_FOO)
    (ERR_OTHER)
)

int main()
{
    std::cout << err_name2(816) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: If, as I suspect, this answer is not acceptable, just leave a comment and I'll remove it.

Comment: this is a really good idea. amazing - it works!
It is not 'not acceptable' .. I has to think about, and perhaps someone has another answer.
Don't remove it - it is an alternative.